# Converting a div to a ul/li while keeping the format the same

Tags: html, css, frontend

- have to create an HTML document that shows  any 20 countries from the data provided.
  Show the flag, name, currency and all regions for each country.
  Use an unordered list to display each item and use CSS to visually group each item (e.g. boundary or a fill colour) without the typical bullet in a list.
  Show the Wikipedia page as a link for each country.

I have to change my code so that I use list elements for my code, and use an unordered list to display each item and then use css to group each item.

I am currently using div. I tried using one big ul with each country being a list item but the format would be different. I also tried swapping my div for li and wrapping the whole thing in a ul but I failed in trying it. Here's a snippet of 2 countries out of the 20.

```css
.country-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
}


/* Style for each country div */

.country {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid #212020;
  padding: 1em;
  /* Increase padding if needed for spacing within each country */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
}


/* Style for the flag image */

.flag {
  /* No need for additional styles here */
}


/* Style for the country name */

.country h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}


/* Style for the Wikipedia link */

.wiki-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-container">
  <div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/ws.png" alt="Flag of Samoa" />
    <h2>Samoa</h2>
    <p>Currency: Euros (EUR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Atua , Fa'asaleleaga , Tuamasaga
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
  </div>

  <div class="country">
    <img class="flag" src="country_flags/pk.png" alt="Flag of Pakistan" />
    <h2>Pakistan</h2>
    <p>Currency: Rupee (PKR)</p>
    <p>Regions: Azad Jammu and Kashmir , Balochistan , Gilgit-Baltistan , Islamabad , Khyber Pakhtunkhwa , Punjab , Sindh
    </p>
    <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is an ‘item’ in the question? Are regions items as well as countries?

Comment: yes, the names, countries,flags and the wikepedia link are all items

Answer (score 0):

So to show each item in the country container as a list item we can define the country container as ul and each item inside it as li and after that you will see ul's dots before each item, so to remove that we can write a little CSS of which i will add snippet down.

```
<div class="country-container">
    <ul class="country">
      <li>
        <img class="flag" src="country_flags/ws.png" alt="Flag of Samoa" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Samoa</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Currency: Euros (EUR)</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Regions: Atua , Fa'asaleleaga , Tuamasaga
      </li>
      </p>
      <li>
        <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa"
        target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="country">
      <li>
        <img class="flag" src="country_flags/ws.png" alt="Flag of Samoa" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Samoa</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Currency: Euros (EUR)</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Regions: Atua , Fa'asaleleaga , Tuamasaga
      </li>
      </p>
      <li>
        <a class="wiki-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa"
        target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

to remove ul's dot :-

```
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

This is my output after this
[image]

Comment: would this be considered an unordered list for all items (flag, country name, currency, wikepedia link)?

Comment: Ahh ok so you need to show each item as a list item, I have updated my answer, you check now